# Why rewrite with error_page to named location doesn't work?

Tags: nginx

Consider nginx settings:

```
server {
    server_name abc.com;
    listen 80;

    location @namedlocation {
        proxy_pass google.com;
    }
    location ~ /some/url {
        rewrite /some/url /another/url break;
        error_page 418 = @namedlocation;
        return 418; 
    }
}
```

If I request abc.com/some/url, then proxy_pass to google.com/another/url does not work. But if I use try_files directive

```
server {
    server_name abc.com;
    listen 80;

    location @namedlocation {
        proxy_pass google.com;
    }
    location ~ /some/url {
        rewrite /some/url /another/url break;
        try_files /NotImportantPath/ @namedlocation; 
    }
}
```

it does. Could you please explain what is the reason for such behavior?

**Closed**

Comment: Flag `break` means stop executing rewrite module directives. A little surprising, but `return` directive is from rewrite module.

Comment: @AlexeyTen, is it true that my usage of try_files directive makes additional I/O operation?

Comment: Just get rid of break

Comment: @AlexeyTen, what if I have multiple rewrites in same location block and only one rewrite can be activated? For example: https://pastebin.com/QqNcfsS8

Comment: Then you're doing something wrong. Ask new question with real rewrites